# Visual studio unable to evaluate anything in debug in any page of my blazor webassembly

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging, blazor-webassembly, vscode-debugger

I have a blazor webassembly app that is working fine and it is split in webassembly talking to a web api version all .Net Code
I use VS community Edition 2019 and suddenly after many modifications to my code I noticed that I am not able to debug and see any variable content(**unable to Evaluate**) at any break points anywhere in my web assembly app. I tried with an old version of my code which I know it was working then and same issue, so it is not the code.
I tried upgrading VS to 16.11.75.64347 ( from 16.6 something) without success and even uninstall & reinstall VS with no success.
The only new thing on my station was a windows update this week.

Is someone had something similar happening this week?
ps: What is weird is that I do not not have this problem in my web API solution portion just the webassembly solution.

Comment: It could be a config problem, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72037574) for working config, if you are using Edge.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've been badluck to find many not working thread but finally it was simply to close VS . delete the .vs directory tehn relod the solution and it was OK.  It is weird though that many old version of my code that never had this issue had the same problem. It was impossible to have all those .vs not working although I had not touched them in weeks.  Anyway it is now working.

Comment: `.vs` folder contains cache of some vs settings for this project and also some debugging information. This folder will be re-generated by VS if your delete it. The debugging information in `.vs` folder may be corrupted by accident, anyway, thanks for sharing your solution, and please don't forget to **[accept your reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** when it is available. Have a great day.